No module named 'pyinstaller'
I want to create an installer for my app but when I tried to run my code I had an error that says that there is no module 'pyinstaller' even if I have this module installed.
This import causes an error in my program:
import pyinstaller.__main__

I am using spyder to run python-3.8.5 but when I run my code it show me
this error message:
runfile('C:/Users/Documents/CalculBride/PyInstaller.py',
wdir='C:/Users/Documents/CalculBride')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Documents\CalculBride\PyInstaller.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyinstaller.__main__

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyinstaller'

I checked with the pip list command, in the spyder console and I had pyinstaller-6.9.0
installed
So I uninstall pyinstaller and install it back again (pyinstaller
6.9.0). Still the same No module named 'pyinstaller'. So I discussed
with someone who could run my code on pyinstaller 3.6 and I tried to
install this version of pyinstaller but I had this error message:

So i try to upgrade pip and i had this error:

I am wondering if it is due to fact I previously installed
auto-py-to-exe (which uses pyinstaller) but even after I uninstalled
auto-py-to-exe there is still this no module named 'pyinstaller' error, even
if I can see that this module is installed when i do a pip list in the
spyder console.

Please don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.

Have you verified that you use the same python version as the one pyinstaller is installed for?

I apologize if my post is not according to the customs of this site, a colleague advised me to post my problem here because we did not understand the reason for this error message. I'm a beginner in computer development and I'd like to thank you for answering my problem despite its triviality.

About the ModuleNotFoundError:
It should be import PyInstaller.__main__ not import pyinstaller.__main__. Notice it's upper case. See the documentation.

About the installation of PyInstaller 3.6:
From the PyInstaller pypi, you will know that PyInstaller 3.6 doesn't work with Python 3.8. It starts to support Python 3.8 from version 4.1. So you can try pip install pyinstaller==4.1.


Thank you very much, I didn't know that a later version of the pyinstaller module (6.9) might not be recognized depending on the version of Python installed. I thought that the most recent version would work for all versions of Python.
